# how to build automatically looping PHP - SQl

Tags: php, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
1. Team
id  group_head  initial_team
id : for id table (auto increment)
Group Head : employee id to add group head
initial team : initial team for this team


2. Team Sub
id  team_id     employee_id     parent  parent_id
id : id for table (auto increment)
team_id : id of the Team_table
employee_id : employee id
parent : value 0 if they child from team_sub, value 1 if they child from team
parent_id : if parent value 1 the parent id is id team, if parent value 0 the parent is id team sub
```

My question :
how to know total childs from team (group head)? Or how to know the bottom child from id team? If I delete id team the child is deleted too..

example :

```
id team : 1

data from team_ sub :
status parent: 1 parent_id : 1 (id this data is 1)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 1 (id this data is 2)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 3)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 3 (id this data is 4)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 4 (id this data is 5) 

id team : 2

data from team_ sub :
status parent: 1 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 6)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 6 (id this data is 7)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 7 (id this data is 8)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 8 (id this data is 9)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 9 (id this data is 10)
```

[image: example on image]

where parent status is 1 , parent_id is id team..
where parent status is 0, parent_id is id team_sub..

this is relation data on image
[image]

sorry if my english is bad...

id team_sub 10 is child from id team 2 and id team_sub 5 is child from id team 1..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can't check it right now, but should be like this if I understood you right :

```
SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent_id = 0)
```

It selects every entry that is technicaly part of the parent_id =1 aka part of the sub_team

If you just want a number of entrys that have this condition :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent_id = 0)
```

exaples:

```
//Count all entries in Team_ID 1:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent_id = 1) 


//Select all entrys in Team_ID 2:


SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent_id = 2) 


//Count all Entries that do belong to an Team_ID:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Team_Sub WHERE NOT (parent_id = 0) 


//Select all Entries that do belong to an Team_ID:

SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE NOT (parent_id = 0)
```

I would recommend following structure:

```
status parent: 1 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 6)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 7)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 8)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 9)
status parent: 0 parent_id : 2 (id this data is 10)
```

In this way you can detemine the Team by "parent_id" and the head of the team by "parent".

so in example like above:

```
id 6 is Head of Team 2
id 7 is Subordinate of Team 2
id 8 is Subordinate of Team 2
id 9 is Subordinate of Team 2
id 10 is Subordinate of Team 2
```

By this you can Query any entry you want by simple determining the "parent_id" and "parent"

e.g.:

```
//Just Heads of any Team:
SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent = 1)

//Just Head of a specific team:
SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent = 1) AND (parent_id="team id")

//Just Subordinates of any Team:
SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent = 0)

//Just Subordinates of a specific team:
SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent = 0) AND (parent_id="team id")

//Just Anybody of a specific team:
SELECT * FROM Team_Sub WHERE (parent_id="team id")
```

***FYI :   if not yet any dependencies on the value-names, id recommend to rename "parent" to "head_of_team" and "parent_id" to "team_id"***

Comment: According to the tag we do speak about SQL :)

Comment: oh ^^  that flag wasn't there when i came here ^^   said PHP only ^^

Comment: in this example just 1 id team. if we use parent_id = 0, every id team have many status where parent_id = 0 .. :-s

Comment: See updated Answer. Should solve any solution you need ( I am expecting you need the "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Team_Sub WHERE NOT (parent_id = 0)" solution

Comment: i was updated my question with image, sorry if my english is bad :(

Comment: OK   Now i got you.   Tell my why the data is using parent_id to substructure the entries instead of pointing directly to the next higher entry

Comment: I'm making the task of the application team. in the team has a group head and each group head has a lot of subordinates. so I created such a database structure .. Are you any suggestions for best database structure?

Comment: Updated answer with possible solution for database structure